# JRI - Newlines in R Code

Tags: java, r, jri

I'm currently using JRI, the Java package in order to use some of the functions provided by R.

Let's say, my R command goes like this:

```
qqnorm(sql_data[["LifeExpectancy"]],
main="Life Expectancy")
```

If I put this into my REngine.eval() function, it crashes, because I'm supposed to enter the whole command into one "eval()" command. It works in my normal R command line though...

The major problem is, that it's hard to predict for me, whenever the next order is split up into multiple lines or not. So, how may I fix that problem?

I thought about counting the brackets, but the number of brackets isn't always even. (Let's say, some brackets are contained in Strings) Any other ideas?

Edit: I think, my point is not obvious enough. Try this out:

```
System.out.println(re.eval("a <- c(3,4)"));
System.out.println(re.eval("a"));

System.out.println(re.eval("b <- c(3,4")); 
System.out.println(re.eval(",5)"));
System.out.println(re.eval("b"));
```

You'll see, that for the first two commands, a, you receive

```
[REAL* (3.0, 4.0)] 
[REAL* (3.0, 4.0)]
```

But the rest, b, goes like this:

```
[NULL ]
[NULL ]
null
```

It's a problem with R in general; usually this works, but not in JRI!

Comment: Please show the line of java code that gives the error and show details of the error.

Comment: It's an error in R, not in Java.

Comment: Please, post an error messagge wherever you receive it. BTW, didn't the error arise by calling `REngine.eval()`?

Comment: `REngine.eval()` needs a valid R statement. Why are you breaking into two or more calls? Are you trying to read an `.R` file line by line and executing each line through `REngine.eval()`? If that's the case, just call `REngine.eval("source('rfile.R')")` and the script will be executed.

Comment: This is possible, whenever using a normal R console. It's just the way, how I get my R commands and I can't really influence it. If you try that out in a normal R command line, it works perfectly. But in JRI, it doesn't! And that's my problem!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looking at  `System.out.println(re.eval("b <- c(3,4"));` i noticed that your error is in R, (typo - missed the second bracket), see the following code, it works:

```
package stackoverflow;

import org.rosuda.JRI.REXP;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;
/**
 *
 * @author yschellekens
 */
public class StackOverflow {  

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] Rargs = {"--vanilla"};
     Rengine rengine = new Rengine(  Rargs, false, null);
        rengine.eval("b <- c(3,4)");
          REXP result=  rengine.eval("b[1]");
      System.out.println(result.asDouble());
   }
}
```

Java output:

```
run:
3.0
```

Notice that you can't pass straight into `System.out.println`  an `Rengine`  object, you need to convert it into an `REXP` object first (see in code).

Also your first example

```
qqnorm(sql_data[["LifeExpectancy"]],
main="Life Expectancy")
```

includes inner " " and hence another reason for a possible crash

Please use : ' ' as following:

```
 qqnorm(sql_data[['LifeExpectancy']],
    main='Life Expectancy')
```